# Help using hook_theme() on custom module

Tags: 7, hooks, theming

I've been writing a custom module to spit a content type into 2 pages, with custom fields accessible via a tab.
For ease I've built the test case on a fresh d7 install and using the predefined article content type.

My module folder has the following files:

[image: module folder view]

Now, the template file is simply a copy of the bartik themes node.tpl.php file, but for some reason the module will not load it. I've read through the hook_theme() page and used the examples for developers theming_example, but I just can't get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-------- UPDATED CODE ----------------

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Implements hook_menu().
     */
    function article_page_menu() {

      $items['node/%/info'] = array(
        'title' => 'Info',
        'page callback' => 'article_page_page_callback',
        'page arguments'   => array(1),
        'access callback' => 'article_page_access_callback',
        'access arguments' => array(1),
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK, // tab instead of MENU_CALLBACK
        'weight' => '1000', // last tab item
      );

      return $items;
    }

    /**
     *  Page Callback
     */
    function article_page_page_callback($nid) {
      if (is_numeric($nid)) {
        $node = node_load($nid);

        if($node->type == 'article') {
          return theme('article_page_template', array('node' => $node));
        }

        drupal_not_found();
        return;
      }
      return FALSE;
    }

    /**
     *  Create the access callback
     */
    function article_page_access_callback($nid) {
      if (is_numeric($nid)) {
        $node = node_load($nid);
        // only show for article types
        if($node->type != 'article'){ 
          return FALSE;
        } else {
          return TRUE;
        }
      }
      return FALSE;
    }

    /**
     * Implements hook_theme().
     */
    function article_page_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
      return array(
        'article_page_template'  => array(
          'template' => 'article_page_template',
        ),
      );
    }

    function theme_article_page_template($variables) {
      $node = $variables['node'];
      $build = node_view($node);
      $output = drupal_render($build);
      return $output;
    }
```

------------ END UPDATED CODE -----------

--------- BELOW IS THE OLD CODE ---------------------

Here is the code from the module file:

```
        <?php
        /**
         * Implements hook_menu().
         */
        function article_page_menu() {

          $items['node/%/info'] = array(
            'title' => 'Info',
            'page callback' => 'article_page_load',
            'page arguments'   => array(1),
            'access callback' => 'article_page_access',
            'access arguments' => array(1),
            'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK, // tab instead of MENU_CALLBACK
            'weight' => '1000', // last tab item
          );

          return $items;
        }

        /**
         * Constructs a descriptive page.
         */
        function article_page_load($nid) {
          if (is_numeric($nid)) {
            $node = node_load($nid);

            if($node->type == 'article') {
              // convert object to array
              // else we get an error
              $build = node_view($node);
              $render = drupal_render($build);
              return $render;
            }
            drupal_not_found();
            return;
          }
          return FALSE;
        }

        /**
         *  Create the access callback
         */
        function article_page_access($nid) {
          if (is_numeric($nid)) {
            $node = node_load($nid);
            // only show for article types
            if($node->type != 'article'){ 
              return FALSE;
            } else {
              return TRUE;
            }
          }
          return FALSE;
        }


        /**
         * Implements hook_theme().
         */
        function article_page_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
          return array(
            'article_page_template'  => array(
              'template' => 'article_page_template',
            ),
          );
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like there are quite a few elements in your module code that are used incorrectly. For example, your page callback should not be a hook (you are using [hook_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!node.php/function/hook_load/6)) and the callback should call [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7) and invoke your custom theme function. In addition, your [hook_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) implementation is incorrect and you will also need to implement [hook_theme_registry_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7) in your module to let the theme system know about your template file.

There is a good example of all this that you can base your code off of in this [comment in the API for hook_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7#comment-14989)

Also, you seem to be mixing together the terms 'node' and 'page' so I am unsure whether you are using the terms correctly (i.e. I'm not sure if you're mistakenly using a node template as your basis when you may really want to use a page template, etc.)

Comment: Hi Sheena and thanks for your answer. I called the module article_page, but it should create a 1 to 1 copy of the full node view (which in the template file is defined as $page == true), but that doesn't work as the elements for if(!page){} are shown. Yes, the template file is the node.tpl.php file and I wish to display the $node and not $page content. So basically I want to display an exact copy of node/1 at the url node/1/info and with use of the template file show the specific fields I need.

Comment: Ok, i've edited my code - it's posted above - now the template is loaded (i know because i added a bit of text in the first line), but none of the defined variables in the template present. I guess I have to call them all using $node->element. Note that I did not use hook_theme_registry_alter. It says: 'Alter the theme registry information returned from hook_theme().' Why would I need to alter the info I set in my hook_theme() function?

Comment: I would say that your issues with creating the additional node page and redering its content are a separate issue from the template call not working and I'd suggest opening an new question for that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have a quick tutorial for hook_theme in D8 here if you need: http://westweb-solutions.com/blog/drupal-8-how-use-hooktheme. It's a bit more tricky, but D8 is gaining ground quickly.